# Hangfire Merge Command Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, hangfire

I am trying to run Hangfire with SQL Server 2005 which does not have datetime2 data type so I found [this discussion](http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/sql-server-2005/94) very helpful. That fixed one problem but it opened another. Now I get the error:

> SqlMapper.cs not found. An exception of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but
>   was not handled in user code. Incorrect syntax near 'merge'.

I found source code for SqlMapper.cs on GitHub. The Dapper.1.38 package is the package I added to my project.  Even so, I get a message that the source file is different from when the module was built.

I did some debugging anyway and was able to find the SQL command that is causing the exception. It is this:

```
merge HangFire.Server as Target 
using (VALUES (@id, @data, @heartbeat)) as Source (Id, Data, Heartbeat) 
on Target.Id = Source.Id 
when matched then 
update set Data = Source.Data, LastHeartbeat = Source.Heartbeat 
when not matched then 
insert (Id, Data, LastHeartbeat) values (Source.Id, Source.Data, Source.Heartbeat);
```

The merge command syntax may not be compatible with SQL Server 2005 but I have not been able to isolate the reason for the exception.  I suspect the VALUES clause.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to re-write it to not use MERGE, or upgrade. There is no way to make MERGE work on SQL Server 2005. It is "new" syntax introduced in SQL Server 2008. I put "new" in quotes because 2008 isn't exactly new, either.

Comment: And if you upgrade, [please read this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).